# How to stop Delphi processing the prefix "&" character in some control captions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I found that if I set the Caption of `TPanel`, `TLabel` or `TRadioGroup` with a string containing "&" character, it is not displayed and the next character is underlined. How can I stop this? I want the caption to be displayed with the exact string I set.

Comment: just use double "*and*" characters:  `&&`

Comment: Agreed, I'd use `StringReplace(Text, '&', '&&', [rfReplaceAll])`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For TLabel and TStaticText, set `ShowAccelChar` property to `False` (default is `True`). For TPanel, TRadioGroup etc you need to use double ampersand.

You may also want to take a look in help for `TLabel.ShowAccelChar`, for a description how `TLabel.ShowAccelChar` and `TLabel.FocusControl` are related.